# Silverlight4.0: Set childwindow field in MainPage not work

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I want to pass some data from MainPage to its childwindow as follows:

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponents();
  ChildWindow childwind = new ChildWindow();
  childwind.textblk1.Text += "Test!";
  //break point here
  ContentFrame.Content = childwind;  
}
```

textblk1 is the name of a TextBlock in ChildWindow. But there is no text "Test!" shown in the page when I run it. Though I work through this problem by just setting the text directly in the ChildWindow's constructor from reading added property in App, I still wonder why the above method failed? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand the usage you are trying but below should be enough if you want to set anything in a ChildWindow.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ChildWindow childwind = new ChildWindow();
    childwind.Content = "Test!";       
    childwind.Show();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Content = "Button is hit";
            ChildWindow1 objchld = new ChildWindow1();
            objchld.label1.Content = "I am child window";
            objchld.Show();
        }
```

hope this will useful for u

Comment: I found the reason is that some code in corresponding .xaml explicitly invoke the ChildWindow and it will generate a new ChildWindow in the page, which hide the former one.
Thank you for your example, it's helpful.